# Best Data Structure For Time Series Data

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, time-series, binary-tree

I wonder if someone could take a minute out of their day to give their two cents on my problem.

I would like some suggestions on what would be the best data structure for representing, on disk, a large data set of time series data.  The main priority is speed of insertion, with other priorities in decreasing order; speed of retrieval, size on disk, size in memory, speed of removal.

I have seen that B+ trees are often used in database because of their fast search times, but how about for fast insertion times?  Is a linked list really the way to go?

Comment: Please describe your data better.  Are you talking about a sequence of timestamps and values (eg how large is something at a given point in time.) Or is the data more complex -- A series of timestamps, values and other data.

Comment: The data is simply a sequence of timestamps and values, no more complex then that.  Thank you.

Comment: If it's time-series data, are most of your "inserts" actually "appends"? That would make quite a difference.

Comment: most of them are appends, yes.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [HDF5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) (Hierarchical Data Format).  It's well suited for Time Series data.  Implementation wise, it uses B Trees.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be just what the doctor ordered!